# Are you able to "talk together"?

Tags: phrase-usage

> **A:** Do you have a good relationship with your ex-husband?
>
> **B:** Define "good."
>
> **A:** Are you able to talk together?
>
> **B:** When we have to.

Is "Are you able to talk together?" a natural way to phrase the question?

Comment: We "talk to each other" much more often than we "talk together."

Comment: That doesn't even seem like right to me. I mean how can two people talk together? Sounds weird to me.

Answer (score 3):

In **colloquial** English, this would be interpreted as intended:

> Two people being able to communicate thoughts by mouth to each other.

Sentences like these, where the preposition doesn't fit with the verb, should be rewritten for clarity.

'Talk' is considered a bland verb in proper English. It should be avoided in formal writing. 'Talk' is also the problematic verb in the sentence.

---

### So let's fix this...

The predicate (action verb) in this sentence is more accurately represented with a better, descriptive, *complex* verb.

- Share feelings/thoughts
- Communicate

If you picked 'Share Feelings' or 'Share Thoughts' you can simply exchange the verbs:

> Are you able to *share feelings* together?

> Are you able to *share thoughts* together?

This works because the action of sharing can have multiple people involved as donors. (The woman and the husband) and can have multiple recipients (also the woman and the husband).

**OR**

If you picked 'communicate' you *cannot* simply exchange the verbs. You may want to change the preposition, which is the recipient of the communication in question.

- With each other
- To each other

Furthermore, (*in this case*) you can omit the target because it can be inferred from the previous sentence.

> Are you able to *communicate* *with each other*?

> Are you able to *communicate*?

---

### TLDR

**Q**: "Is it natural?"

**A**: Yes, but it's informal.

**Q**: "Should I change it if I can?"

**A**: Please.

Comment: Fabulous answer! Welcome to ELL and thanks for putting in the time and effort!